# How to get the values of a column from a table in jQuery into a multidimentional array

Tags: jquery, arrays

I have a table that is something like this

```
<table width="60%">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <th>Corredor Feed</th>
            <th>Nombre</th>
            <th>Empressa</th>
            <th>Pagina Web</th>
            <th>Telefono</th>
            <th>Cellular</th>
        </tr>
       <tr class="row">
            <td>info@saeinmobiliario.com
                <input type="hidden" value="info@saeinmobiliario.com" name="email[]"/>
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="input" value="" class="validate" name="nombre[]"/>
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="input" value="" name="empressa[]"/>
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="input" value="" name="paginaWeb[]"/>
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="input" value="" name="telefono[]"/>
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="input" value="" name="cellular[]"/>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td align="right" colspan="6">
                <input type="submit" value="Enviar" name="submitme"/>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

I am trying to create a multi dimensional array from the values obtained from each row in jQuery I have thought of a script like this

```
$('.row').each(function (i) {
                    $(this).find('td').each(function (j) {
                        /*if (j == 5) {
                            var x = $(this).find("input").val();
                            feed.push({
                                cellular: x
                            });
                        }*/
              //here I have to create an array that will hold value of each row 


                    });

                });
});
```

But I do not know how to push the values from the input type of each row into a multi dimensional array

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/52v1pyoz/)
Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<table width="60%">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <th>Corredor Feed</th>
            <th>Nombre</th>
            <th>Empressa</th>
            <th>Pagina Web</th>
            <th>Telefono</th>
            <th>Cellular</th>
        </tr>
        <tr class="row">
            <td>info@saeinmobiliario.com
                <input type="hidden" value="info@saeinmobiliario.com" name="email[]" />
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="input" value="1" class="validate" name="nombre[]" />
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="input" value="2" name="empressa[]" />
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="input" value="3" name="paginaWeb[]" />
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="input" value="4" name="telefono[]" />
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="input" value="5" name="cellular[]" />
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="row">
            <td>info@saeinmobiliario.com
                <input type="hidden" value="info2@saeinmobiliario.com" name="email[]" />
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="input" value="2-1" class="validate" name="nombre[]" />
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="input" value="2-2" name="empressa[]" />
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="input" value="2-3" name="paginaWeb[]" />
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="input" value="2-4" name="telefono[]" />
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="input" value="2-5" name="cellular[]" />
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td align="right" colspan="6">
                <input type="submit" value="Enviar" name="submitme" />
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>

<script>
var rows = new Array();
var row = new Array();

$('.row').each(function (i) {
    row = [];
    $(this).find('td').each(function (j) {
        row.push($(this).find("input").val());
    });
    rows.push(row);
});
alert(JSON.stringify(rows));
</script>
```

Comment: this will only return last row. You're wiping `row` array on each loop.

Comment: `row = [];` will create a new empty reference. You only can't access the original array by its variable (`row`), but the pushed array into the rows array will be accessible through rows[x][y]. Try it in fiddle, it works.

Comment: `var a = new Array(), b = new Array(); 
a.push('something');
b = a;
a = [];
alert(b[0]);`

This will output 'something', however the `a` array was set to [].

Answer (score 2):

Create a new `array` and `object`, loop through rows's content. Inside each row, retrieve `input`'s `name` and `value` attributes. Add them to `object` and then `.push()` that `object` into *rows* `array`.

```
var rows = [];
$('.row').each(function (i) {
    var content = {};
    $(this).find('td').each(function (j, v) {
        var input = $("input", this),
            name = input.attr("name").substring(0, input.attr("name").length - 2),
            value = input.val();
        content[name] = value;
    });
    rows.push(content);
});
```

Here is a [working example](http://jsfiddle.net/4fgr74u9/).